# How to redirect to another page in JQuery if the variable is Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect the browser to the login page if `SESSION` is not set and a customer clicks on `Add to cart` button.

I Have written this code  `window.location.replace("http://app.test/pages/login.php");` for redirecting to the login page if the `customer_id` is empty. but it doesn't redirect to this page.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            CountProducts();
            $('.add_cart').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $container = $(this).closest('.col-sm-12');

                var name = $container.find('.name').val();
                var hiddenID = $container.find('.hiddenID').val();
                var price = $container.find('.price').val();
                var category = $container.find('.category').val();
                var customer_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['customer_id']?>;
                if(customer_id === '')
                   {
                       window.location.replace("http://app.test/pages/login.php");
                   }
                   else{
                   $.ajax({
                    url: "Ajax/add_to_cart.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        name: name,
                        hiddenID: hiddenID,
                        price: price,
                        category: category
                    },
                    success: function(output) {
                        CountProducts();
                    }
                });
                   }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://app.test/pages/login.php";`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Use simple location = "http://app.test/pages/login.php";

Comment: not working. not redirecting to the page

Comment: "not redirecting"... ok so what _is_ happening? have you checked for errors? Have you debugged the code? Is it definitely executing the location.href command? If not, is there an error in the Javascript? Or is the `if` statement before it not returning true? Perhaps customer_id doesn't contain the value you expect? Or maybe the command runs but doesn't go to the page you wanted? If so, what error do you get? Telling us what is actually happening is far more valuable than telling us what isn't happening. Perhaps even if you make these simple investigations you'll end up solving it yourself.

Comment: no error is showing. not redirecting the page nor refreshing the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
if( customer_id > 0 ) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "Ajax/add_to_cart.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        hiddenID: hiddenID,
        price: price,
        category: category
    },
    success: function(output) {
        CountProducts();
    }
  });
}
else {
    window.location.href = "http://app.test/pages/login.php";
}
```

Comment: it's ok to suggest some code, but why? What do you think the problem is? What did you change? Why does this solve it? An answer with an explanation is 100% more useful, otherwise people are just encouraged to blindly copy and paste code without knowing the implications or whether it solves their specific issue. (And before you say, if they already understand your code then probably they could have written it themselves in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thanks for Helping. I forgot to put this code `var customer_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['customer_id']?>;` in quotes Now i write it like this `var customer_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['customer_id']?>';` and it works.